# Power Platform environments - security groups - control of sharing

Tags: power-platform

I want to create an environment in Power Platform which will allow makers to create apps and flows, but will not allow them to be shared.

I have created an environment, configured a "team" and attached it to an AAD security group for access control - this seems to work well.

I have then associated the team with a custom security group. The group is a copy of "Environment Maker" but with the sharing attribute on canvas apps set to "none"

When I apply this - makers loose the ability to create apps, when I switch back to Environment Maker, then apps can be created. (but are shareable)

With the custom group applied the preview for the environment displays like this: Role = "Shared app contributor", when I can create apps it's "Maker without full data access"

Can anyone please fill me in on what's is going wrong here? Or an alternative approach please.

I tried customising the Environment Maker Group by creating a copy then removing the sharing property. This has other impacts which I can't figure out and prevents makers from creating apps.